# What is this blue bar on my Windows 7 desktop?

Tags: windows-7, desktop, start-menu

Normally I keep my Start Bar at the top of my screen. Some applications don't realize this and open underneath it. It means I have to move the start bar out of the way to get at the window controls for that app. Normally, I just move it to the side and move it back when I'm done.

However, in Windows 7, a blue bar is left in the start bar's place afterward.

[image]

It blurs the objects underneath, but passes down mouse events so click and move events still work.

Anyone know what this is or how to get rid of it?

**EDIT:** It appears that when I move the start bar back to bottom of the screen and back to the top the "glitch" is removed.

(Windows 7 RC Build 7100)

Comment: I think you got that build number wrong... it's 7100 not 1700

Comment: Just a tip. Instead of moving the taskbar when it covers a window..Hold down the windows button and push the arrow keys. That should resize the current window to where you can access the top controls.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Having played around a bit on my own Win7 machine, it looks like it's a "ghost" of the task bar - probably a bug.  I got rid of it by moving the task bar around the screen until the "ghost" disappeared and the bar was where I wanted it.  I think the most reliable move was from bottom to top.

Comment: This was mentioned in the release notes (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd367847.aspx) of the Win 7 RC as a known bug which will be fixed until RTM.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like a [known bug](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itproui/thread/199a6cca-2917-4502-87fd-9cc7cb0f0032).  The discussion indicates it may be video driver related, but can't find anything official on that.